# Using "in" parameter modifier with int/long/etc (alias Int32/Int64 non-readonly-structs)

Tags: c#

Does it make any sense to use "in" parameter modifier with int/long/etc...? int/long and the others are not readonly structs...or better, does it only make sense to use "in" parameter modifier with user defined readonly structs?

Comment: This is only a conceptual question (and just for structs)...I've been spending some time reading posts related on when to use the "in" parameter modifier and its pros and cons...when you use the "in" with structs, the recommended is to use it only when the structs are defined as readonly - but the curious thing is that largely all the examples are using values declared as int (which are aliased to Int32 structs, which at the same time, are not readonly structs? So, maybe I'm missing something, but it seems that to avoid the compiler defensive copy you should use readonly structs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while it expresses a certain *intent*, it changes the semantics a lot, and it changes the stack semantics a lot - for things like `int` it increases the space used (on x64, at least). Of course, the JIT *may* be able to remove that.

The *intended* usage is really on `readonly struct` - in particular, ones that are relatively large, so: passing a reference is much cheaper than passing the value, and the `in` means you don't need a defensive copy. But: if the type *isn't* `readonly`, then the *compiler* adds a defensive copy inside any method that takes an `in` parameter on a non-`readonly` type and does something that looks unsafe.

I wouldn't bother with it for `int`, `long`, but: if you really need to know: use `BenchmarkDotNet` on a representative scenario.

Comment: I've just been experimenting with this (to remind myself of what goes on), and the defensive copy is at the call site of a method *on the parameter* - it's not at the call site of the method that has the `in` parameter. It may be worth clarifying that. (I'm slightly surprised that `decimal` isn't known to be read-only...)

Comment: @DaisyShipton I *think* I've clarified it... possibly not, though :)

Comment: Yes, totally agree...but then, a certain "design" intent may make you to fall into performance penalties, because, even for int, long, etc, the compiler will generate a defensive copy...and this is aggravated if you are using it in expensive code paths (like very large loops). Definitely, my intend is only use it only with readonly structs - specifically for tokens in a parser -...I don't really see another advantage...other than the design intent to mark the parameter as in (ref readonly) specifically for user defined structs...

Comment: @EmilioV one nice thing about it is that it makes it possible to implement extension methods on structs using by-ref semantics; previously this wasn't really possible as the language folks didn't like the idea of an invisible `ref`, as it might not be clear that the state could change (which isn't normally possible on an extension method, as it is a copy) - especially since methods on structs can have very odd side-effects; the combination of `readonly` and `in` tidy up a few things in that area

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yup, that's better. Thanks!